# Can we use Route 53 or any Managed DNS for Azure VM Virtual IP?

Tags: windows, azure, smtp, azure-virtual-machine, reverse-dns

I have deployed application to Win Azure Virtual Machine.
but when i try to send email, almost all S.M.T.P. rejects my Message or sends it to spam.

i have set up SPF + DKIM + Dmarc on my domain.

only one thing i suppose the problem should be is PTR for my VIP of VM.

Can i Use Route 53 for that?

or I should use other SMTP provider like... sendgrid, Amazon SES ?

please Help friends

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure don't allow us to add PTR record for our VIP of Virtual machine. So, many mail server will consider mail as spam message.

Right now we are using Amazon SES and it works very well and also far cheaper than SendGrid.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to send email directly from Azure. It will almost certainly be treated as spam. It's hard enough setting up a valid email server to send mail. Adding a scalable provider to the mix only makes it more complicated to avoid getting flagged.

[SendGrid](http://www.sendgrid.com) integrates very nicely, and can be configured via SMTP or through use of their API. [Here are instructions from Microsoft on how to get up and running quickly.](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/sendgrid-email-service/)

Also, here is a similar question on [ServerFault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/478076/can-an-email-server-be-set-up-on-an-azure-vm)